# Can you give some advise about 3D simulation engine (choose best one but how?) in winforms 3d and wpf 3d?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, 3d

Can you give some advise winforms 3d and wpf 3d?
Question:
i try to write a simulation program 3D in windows forms i have some knowledge about 
CsGL (OpenGl wrapper)
DirectX 
OPenTk

Also
 
SlimDx
OgreDotNet

WPF :
Balder

i have 2 question:
1) do you give some advise about above engines to create some simulation. Or any other best engine or wrapper class

2) Can i use Balder in  Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only visualization, I can recommend you opensource visualization library [VTK](http://vtk.org/)

But if you also need geometry computing (meshing, intersection and so on), I can advice another open source library [OpenCascade](http://www.opencascade.org/)

As example of using both of it, go to [SALOME](http://salome-platform.org/) project. The last one also can be used as a platform of simulating application, but it's based on Qt library.

Comment: But i have vs 2008 and vs 2010 i am coding C#

Comment: But i have used vs 2008 and 2010 C# VTK or OpenCascade Salome is sufficient for C#

Comment: For VTK and C# you can go http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK_Tools and download "VTK Wrapper for .NET". Originally it's for vs2005, but I think it should be no problem to compile on under the vs2008.